# How to extract a decimal number from a string, map it to a categorical description, and append this description to the string?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```js
[
  ' |Time:12:00 |Tracking ID:  1   |Dim: 0.01 , 
  ' |Time: 12:01  |Tracking ID:  2  |Dim: 0.02, 
  ' |Time: 12:02  |Tracking ID: 3  |Dim: 0.03 , 
  ' |Time: 12:04  |Tracking ID:  4  |Dim: 0.04,  
  ' |Time: 12:05  |Tracking ID:  5   |Dim: 0.04 , 
];
```

This is the output i need at the end from the original text file, so for the 5th column " distance" , i need to divide dimension in three categories and display the respective category for each dimension in the "distance" column.

How can i do that ?

Comment: Please paste actual text (like your last question), not a screenshot.  Otherwise you are asking anyone interested in helping you, to actually transcribe the image themselves.

Comment: "How can I do that?" is not generally an appropriate question for Stackoverflow. A more specific question, usually after having made an attempt and showing your work, is expected. Please read [ask] in the Help Center.

Comment: I am new to Stackoverflow. Thank you for the advice Stephen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code iterates over every string, captures (with `RegExp`) the sequence of digits and possible decimal point following the word `'Dim'`, coerces it to an actual number with `+`, then determines the category and appends it to the string.

```js
const SIX_FEET = 0.02;
const SIXTEEN_FEET = 0.079;

const input = [
  ' |Time: 02:49:26.866  |Tracking ID:  1592189362433  |Raw Temperature: 33.270588 |Dim: 0.062500  |Distance: ',
  ' |Time: 02:49:27.295  |Tracking ID:  1592189362433  |Raw Temperature: 33.215687 |Dim: 0.065625  |Distance: ',
  ' |Time: 02:49:27.500  |Tracking ID:  1592189362433  |Raw Temperature: 33.325489 |Dim: 0.062500  |Distance: ',
  ' |Time: 02:49:39.318  |Tracking ID:  1592189370626  |Raw Temperature: 32.666668 |Dim: 0.053125  |Distance: ',
  ' |Time: 02:49:39.585  |Tracking ID:  1592189370626  |Raw Temperature: 32.941177 |Dim: 0.053125  |Distance: '
];

const output = input.map((string) => {
  const dim = +string.match(/Dim: ([\d\.]+)/)[1];
  const category = (dim <= SIX_FEET)
    ? '6 feet or less'
    : (dim >= SIXTEEN_FEET)
      ? '16 feet or greater'
      : '6 to 16 feet';
  return string + category;
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: the code works exactly as expected. But, my  actual data in "input" field is too long(almost 2200 entries) so gives me error. is there any way if i can store it in text file and then add it in "input " field or so?

Comment: Did the error say "Target altitude exceeded"?  If so, the nose of the craft should be tilted slightly downwards.

Comment: can i somehow read the file instead and fetch the values in "input" field?

Comment: Please ask a new question.  It is not clear at all why you do not simply enclose it in a string, given that you understand that's precisely the problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221237/discussion-between-kristy-and-girkovarpa).

Answer (score 0):

An `if else if else` can help if I got your question correctly.

For example, `foreach Dimension`

```
let dist

if (dim <= 0.02) {

  // set dist to 16 feet
  dist = 16;

} else if (dim >= 0.07) {

  // set dist to 6 feet
  dist = 6;

}else {
  // Do something else
}
```